# How to selected value from dropdownList URL aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a popupButton (custom component) in my aspx page. (Car.aspx)

This button has a URL that calls a new view. (Color.aspx)

I would like to pass as a URL parameter a selected value from the dropdown on the Car.aspx page

I tried the code below but it does not send the selected value in the request but the text `<%:ddlCodMercado.SelectedValue%>`

Cars.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlCodMercado" style="Z-INDEX: 111; LEFT: 10px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 50px" runat="server" Width="130px" accessKey="R" CssClass="campo" tabIndex="2">
    <asp:ListItem Value="3433">3433</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3431">3431</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<gvs:popupbutton id="pubConcessionaria" style="Z-INDEX: 109; LEFT: 400px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 50px"
     tabIndex="2" runat="server"  ImageUrl="../img/img_lupa.gif" URL="../Pop-ups/Color_pop.aspx?codMercado=<%:ddlCodMercado.SelectedValue%>"></gvs:popupbutton>
```

How to pass selected value from dropwdown?

Comment: You cannot set the selected value that way. When the page is build the selection is not yet made to it won't show up in the URL. Either use a PostBack to set the url or use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlCodMercado" style="Z-INDEX: 111; LEFT: 10px; 
POSITION: absolute; TOP: 50px" runat="server" Width="130px" accessKey="R" 
CssClass="campo" tabIndex="2">
   <asp:ListItem Value="3433">3433</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3431">3431</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<gvs:popupbutton id="pubConcessionaria" style="Z-INDEX: 109; LEFT: 400px; 
POSITION: absolute; TOP: 50px"
tabIndex="2" runat="server"  ImageUrl="../img/img_lupa.gif" URL='<%# 
string.Format("../Pop-ups/Color_pop.aspx?codMercado={0}", 
ddlCodMercado.SelectedValue) %>'></gvs:popupbutton>
```